# Why is EMA not equal when comparing samples of different length?

Tags: r, quantmod

I am struggling to understand why EMA (Exponential Moving Average) is different in these 2 cases.

```
options(scipen = 10)
library(quantmod)

getSymbols("AAPL", src = "google")

data1 <- EMA(AAPL[, "AAPL.Close"])
data2 <- EMA(tail(AAPL[, "AAPL.Close"], n = 10))

result <- data.frame(tail(data1, n = 1), tail(data2, n = 1))
```

In the first EMA call i supply as parameter the whole AAPL sample. In the second EMA call i supply only the minimum amount of data to calculate EMA for the last date. If i compare calculated value for the last day, they are different.

In concrete, result[1,1] is 152.907 and result[1,2] is 152.623. Why is this happening? I would expect both numbers to be the same, since EMA is not cumulative.

Comment: See the *Warning* section in `?EMA`. It explains why, and gives an example similar to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the exponential decay has 'infinite' history: it decays, but never completely goes away.

So the set of weights is different between your two use cases, and hence so is the result.  There is a decent recent series on MAs for smoothing price series:

- [part one](http://blog.alphaarchitect.com/2017/07/14/trend-following-with-valeriy-zakamulin-moving-average-basics-part-1/#gs.eml7C80)
- [part two](http://blog.alphaarchitect.com/2017/07/21/trend-following-valeriy-zakamulin-types-moving-averages-part-2/)

It should make it clear that what you were expecting only holds for SMA which does in fact go to zero weights.

Comment: Thank you Dirk. My original intention was to calculate EMA for a time series and then reconcile it with EMA calculated on day by day basis (without recalculating the whole history). Do you see any way how to add observations to existing EMA series that would match the values as when EMA is computed all at once?